# How to read Json Format

Tags: java, android, json

am a android application programmer and working on JSON right now, i have a format of json, shown in below. i am getting such format form server to my android program but the  problem is  am unable to show the result in listview.
could provide me the logic to read that json format.

```
{
"1":
    {
        "sub1":{"marks":"10",
            "maxmarks":"60",
            "grade":"D"
            },
        "sub2":{"marks":"",
            "maxmarks":"60",
            "grade":""
            }
    },
"2":
    {
        "sub3":{"marks":"30",
            "maxmarks":"60",
            "grade":"B"
            },
        "sub4":{"marks":"",
            "maxmarks":"60",
            "grade":""
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: So in your case you have only JSONObjects in your file so have look at some tutorial about parsing JSONObject. Google will be your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Use the JSONObject in Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Here is a good tutorial: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

For example:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(<your json string>); 
JSONObject objectOne = json.getJSONObject("1");
JSONObject subOne = objectOne.getJSONObject("sub1");
string marksOne = subOne.getString("marks");
string maxMarksOne = subOne.getString("maxmarks");
string gradeOne = subOne.getString("grade");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is number of libraries that can help you with the task like [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) or [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Comment: Yes, but not everybody likes the default option ;) with few annotations and POJOs in GSON or Jackson I can easily get out all what I need instead of lengthy coding of Android default option

Comment: True, mapping can be really handy when using complex JSON data!

Answer (score 0):

What info are you trying to show in your ListView?  That will help us help you parse it.

For starters you can separate the data from the two objects using...

```
    //Assuming your original object is named responseObj
    JSONObject obj1 = responseObj.getJSONObject("1");
    JSONObject obj2 = responseObj.getJSONObject("2");

    //Now to get each piece of data
    JSONObject s1 = obj1.getJSONObject("sub1");
    string marks1 = s1.getString("marks");
    string maxMarks1 = s1.getString("maxmarks");
    string grade1 = s1.getString("grade");

    JSONObject s3 = obj2.getJSONObject("sub3");
    string marks3 = s3.getString("marks");
    string maxMarks3 = s3.getString("maxmarks");
    string grade3 = s3.getString("grade");
```

From here you have all of the data and can add them to a ListView in a TextView